# Failing to generate set of RadioButtons Dynamically with Different "Content"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, radio-button

I am a C++ Developer and recently shifted to C#. I am using MVVM pattern in my wpf app. I am working on dynamic generation of radiobuttons. Well the requirement is quiet simple, I need to generate 24 Radiobuttons in such a way that only one radiobutton is checked at one time. Here Is the code:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <GroupBox Header="Daughter Cards" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />                        
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="220" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                    <RadioButton Content="{Binding SlotButtons}" Name="SLotButtons" />
                </Grid> 
            </Grid>
         </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

In `Grid.Column="0"` I want to generate 24 radiobuttons as i discussed above.

**ViewModel:**

```
// Description of SlotButtons
    private string _SlotButtons;
    public string SlotButtons
    {
        get
        {
            return _SlotButtons;
        }

        set
        {
            _SlotButtons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SlotButtons");
        }
    }

//For RadioButton Click
private ICommand mSlotCommand;
    public ICommand SlotCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mSlotCommand == null)
                mSlotCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(mSlotCommandExecuted), new Func<bool>(mSlotCommandCanExecute));

            return mSlotCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            mSlotCommand = value;
        }
    }

    public bool mSlotCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void mSlotCommandExecuted()
    {
       // Logic to implement on a specific radiobutton click using Index
    }
```

I had done this in my C++ app as follows:

```
for(slot = 0; slot < 24; slot++)
{
    m_slotButton[slot] = new ToggleButton(String(int(slot)) + String(": None"));
    m_slotButton[slot]->addButtonListener(this);  // make this panel grab the button press      
    addAndMakeVisible(m_slotButton[slot]);
}
```

Now this is what i want to achieve:

1. Generate 24 RadioButtons with content from `Content = 0: None` till `23: None`.
2. Radiobuttons should be generated in such a way that we divide the row into 3 columns and add 8 radiobuttons in each column vertically.
3. At any time, only one radiobutton must be checked and others must not be checked. There must be only one click command which handles all buttons with the help of respective indexes.

Please help :)

Comment: If you want to use MVVM, you don't create the RadioButtons manually. You use an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate that contains a RadioButton and bind a list of 24 items to the ItemsSource property

Comment: And to get the 8*3 grid layout, you can just use a UniformGrid in the ItemControl's ItemsPanel template

Comment: @nikie: Yes I have already implemented that once. But I find a issue there: All the radiobuttons get checked when i click them, i.e. at one time oly one must be checked :)

Comment: @StonedJesus: Then you have a problem with your implementation. Either you are not creating 24 different sources, or you are not binding properly to the correct ones. nikie's solution is the correct one with MVVM.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: Wait ill update the question with the Nikie's implementation :)

Comment: If you want that only one RB can be checked, they must have the same GroupName, so add `GroupName="SomeName"` to the RadioButton in the ItemTemplate and it should work.

Comment: @FlorianGl: Have a look at the answer :)

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: Have a look at the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need your `SlotCommand`. Instead just bind the `IsChecked` property of each radio button to a boolean property on your viewmodel.

eg:
XAML:

```
<RadioButton Content="{Binding SlotButtons}" Margin="0,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" GroupName="SlotGroup" Height="15" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SlotViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private _isChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { _isChecked = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }
    }
}
```

If you want to react in some way when it gets checked, just do it in the `IsChecked` setter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is How I achieved it:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SlotChildren}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="8" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton Content="{Binding SlotButtons}" Margin="0,10,0,0" Command="{Binding SlotCommand}" Height="15" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
```

**ViewModel Class:**

```
public ObservableCollection<EEPROMSlotViewModel> SlotChildren { get; set; }

SlotChildren = new ObservableCollection<EEPROMSlotViewModel>();
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "0 : None", ID = 0 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "1 : None", ID = 1 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "2 : None", ID = 2 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "3 : None", ID = 3 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "4 : None", ID = 4 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "5 : None", ID = 5 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "6 : None", ID = 6 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "7 : None", ID = 7 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "8 : None", ID = 8 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "9 : None", ID = 9 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "10 : None", ID = 10 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "11 : None", ID = 11 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "12 : None", ID = 12 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "13 : None", ID = 13 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "14 : None", ID = 14 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "15: None", ID = 15 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "16 : None", ID = 16 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "17 : None", ID = 17 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "18 : None", ID = 18 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "19 : None", ID = 19 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "20 : None", ID = 20 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "21 : None", ID = 21 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "22 : None", ID = 22 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { SlotButtons = "23 : None", ID = 23 });
```

**ANother ViewModel Class:** DataContext of XAML is set to this ViewModel Class

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Event for Slot Command Button
    /// </summary>
    private ICommand mSlotCommand;
    public ICommand SlotCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mSlotCommand == null)
                mSlotCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(mSlotCommandExecuted), new Func<bool>(mSlotCommandCanExecute));

            return mSlotCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            mSlotCommand = value;
        }
    }

    public bool mSlotCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void mSlotCommandExecuted()
    {

    }
```

But still all radiobuttons are getting checked. How to clear it?

Answer (score 0):

Add explicitly "Groupname" to your Radio button.

```
<RadioButton GroupName="myGroup" Content="{Binding SlotButtons}" Margin="0,10,0,0" Command="{Binding SlotCommand}" Height="15" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

This will allow only one radio button to check.